# True or False: A partition has an interface file, and zero or more implementation files

Tags: c++, module

An article published on **Microsoft Learn** entitled [Named modules tutorial (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) makes this statement:

> A partition has an interface file, and zero or more implementation files.

This appears to be a flat statement that every partition must have an interface file, even if no names are exported from the partition.

The statement appears near the end of the article, in the section [Module partition files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#module-partition-files). I saw the same statement in a [blog post at modernescpp.com](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-divide-modules/).

**Question:** Is this true for ISO Standard C++, or is this a limitation imposed by Microsoft on its implementation of modules?

###### An example from the C++ Standard

When I attempted to answer this question by consulting the C++ Standard, I found no direct statement, one way or the other.

I did, however, find an example in which a partition named `A:Internals` does not have a partition interface unit. That is a strong indication that the Microsoft limitation does not apply to the standard.

At the same time, the example reinforces the notion that the Microsoft implementation of modules *requires* that a partition have an interface unit. Without one, the example will not compile under MSVC.

Section 10.1 [module.unit](https://eel.is/c++draft/module.unit) of the C++ Standard contains this example:

```cpp
// A.ixx
// Translation unit #1:
export module A;
export import :Foo;
export int baz();
```

```cpp
// A-Foo.ixx
// Translation unit #2:
export module A:Foo;
import :Internals;
export int foo() { return 2 * (bar() + 1); }
```

```cpp
// A-Internals.cpp
// Translation unit #3:
module A:Internals;
int bar();
```

```cpp
// A.cpp
// Translation unit #4:
module A;
import :Internals;
int bar() { return baz() - 10; }
int baz() { return 30; }
```

I added the following module containing function `main`, a simple driver that calls functions `foo` and `baz`.

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;
import std;
import A;
export int main() {
    std::cout 
        << "\nfoo() : " << foo()
        << "\nbaz() : " << baz() 
        << "\n\n";
}
```

When I compiled under MSVC, I got the following error:

> error C7621: module partition 'Internals' for module unit 'A' was not found

True to its word, Microsoft won't compile this unless the partition `Internals` has a partition interface file to go along with its partition implementation unit.

When I supplied one, the program compiled and ran correctly. Note that no names are exported from this partition:

```cpp
// A-Internals.ixx
// Translation unit #5:
export module A:Internals;
int bar();
```

Output:

```
foo() : 42
baz() : 30
```

This example may be the answer to my question: *ISO C++ does not require that a partition have an interface unit, but Microsoft does.*

Outside of the example, however, there should be definitive language in the standard that answers my question. I just could not find it. So I still have a lingering uncertainty: Is it true that "a partition has an interface file, and zero or more implementation files," or is that only a Microsoft limitation?

What is the language in the standard that answers this?

###### Not sure about Clang and GCC

My tests were all conducted with MSVC. I am not sure how Clang and GCC handle this program.

Comment: I would read this as less of a normative statement ("how things must be"), but rather an overwhelmingly-typical-use case statement ("this is what you will most often encounter"), regardless of it being made as a categorical statement.

Comment: Thanks, @SoronelHaetir. You are right, as was explained to me by a Microsoft technician. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### The short answer is FALSE.

It is not always true that "A partition has an interface file, and zero or more implementation files."

The [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#module-partition-files) decribes a common circumstance, but not all circumstances. Some module partitions, such as `A-Internals.cpp` in the original question (i.e., "Translation unit #3), do not have an interface. Those partitions are called *internal partitions*.

The Microsoft compiler has a switch that must be used in order to compile an internal partition. Without it, the compiler is unable to recognize that a partition is an internal partition. That is why the compiler declared an error when I tried to compile the example from the ISO standard.

In the IDE, you set this switch in the Properties dialog box for the individual file. Go to `C++`, `All Options`, and look for "Compile as". Select the setting `Compile as C++ Module Internal Partition (/internalPartition )`.

From the command line, you can just add the switch to the `cl` command.

```
cl /std:c++latest /internalPartition /c A-Internals.cpp
```

With this switch set, I was able to compile and run the program in the original question, without supplying an interface partition, i.e., without including `A-Internals.ixx` (Translation unit #5) as part of the project.

Thanks to the Microsoft technician at its [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com) who helped me with this. In addition to solving my compilation problem, he also accepted my suggestion that the language in the [article at Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#module-partition-files) be changed to:

> Most partitions have an interface file, and zero or more implementation files.

> If, however, a partition does not export any names, it can be implemented as an *internal partition.* Internal partitions do not have an interface file. Internal partitions must be compiled with the option `Compile as C++ Module Internal Partition (/internalPartition)`.